# jQuery input field change time using .split() method

Tags: jquery, time, datetimepicker

I have question for jQuery script just can´t get it work.

Actually, I have two input fields with different time values for START and FINISH TIME of event splitted by ":". (ex. 08:00 and the other field 16:00)

All I need now, is when user click on some button called for ex. "30minutes" this input field with FINISH TIME takes value from START TIME input and what is most important it adds these 30 minutes at the end, so this field will finally change for 08:30. Like it will be 30minutes event. Do you understand my explanation?

What I finally did on JFiddle is similiar, the problem is that these 30 minutes rest at the end, but it is not overwriting the old 00 minutes.

Let´s take a look: [JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/scree/9EUrh/)

### HTML :

```
<input type="radio" name="adds" id="30min" value="30">
<input type="radio" name="adds" id="45min" value="45">
</div>
<input id="start_time" type="text" value="08:00">
<input id="end_time" type="text" value="16:00">
```

### Javascript :

```
$( "#30min" ).click(function() {
    var text = $("#end_time").val().split(" : ");
        var text = $("#start_time").val().split(" : ");
    text[1] = $("#30min").val()
  $( "input" ).val( text );
});
```

thanks for any tips ...

Comment: JFIDDLE link missing ...

Comment: where is the fiddle ?

Comment: I don't know if its possible but when I need to do things like this I use [moment](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this what you want,

```
$("#30min,#45min" ).click(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    $( "input#start_time, input#end_time" ).each(function(e){
      var text = $(this).val();
        var textArr = text.split(":");  
        textArr[1] = that.val();
        $(this).val(textArr[0]+':'+textArr[1]);
    })

});
```

Please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9EUrh/3/)

Comment: Nisam that´s exactly what I am looking for thank you and sorry for my JFiddle link. I have to teach myself how to make JFiddle code public. Thank again.